# Truncate the time portion in a date in Talend

Tags: java, etl, talend

Im joining 3 input tables using tMap component in Talend.Both input & output tables are in a same oracle schema. One of the column of an input table holds DATE datatype of oracle having date-time value.My requirement is to trunc(date) & flow only the date part, meaning removing the time, in output table.

In oracle sql there is a trunc() function to do that job. But how to perform it in Talend7.3 ?

Comment: Assuming your date input is of type 'Date' and its format is 'yyyy-MM-dd', you can use `TalendDate.formatDate("yyyy-MM-dd", [your date input as date type])` to generate a string that contains only the date part.  If you need to convert this string back into a date type, the method `TalendDate.parseDate("yyyy-MM-dd", [string])` can be applied.

Comment: But im passing oracle-specific format i.e. dd-mon-rr. SO every time im using format_date, talend throws error.